# WCF Services Library for Desktop Application to connect MS SQL Database on Virtual machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2019

do I need create WCF Services Library for Desktop Application to connect MS SQL Database on Virtual machine?

Comment: WCF has nothing to do with connecting to databases, no matter where they're stored. The data access library is ADO.NET.

Comment: Thank you sir Panagiotis Kanavos! if I have a Azure subscription, can I connect directly without WCF?

Answer (score 0):

You can access MS SQL Database via the standard NET classes `(System.Data.SqlClient)`. It is not necessary to connect through wcf. Here is the code:

```
public static ProductList GetProducts(string connectionString)
{
    const string GetProductsQuery = "select ProductID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit," +
        " UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, Products.CategoryID " +
        " from Products inner join Categories on Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID " +
        " where Discontinued = 0";

    var products = new ProductList();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = GetProductsQuery;
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var product = new Product();
                            product.ProductID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            product.ProductName = reader.GetString(1);
                            product.QuantityPerUnit = reader.GetString(2);
                            product.UnitPrice = reader.GetDecimal(3);
                            product.UnitsInStock = reader.GetInt16(4);
                            product.CategoryId = reader.GetInt32(5);
                            products.Add(product);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return products;
    }
    catch (Exception eSql)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + eSql.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `if (conn.State == ` isn't needed. `Open()` will either open the connection or throw an exception

Comment: If added, can it be used normally.

Comment: Woww.. thank you sir Jiayao!, I appreciate you very much. so, if I have a Azure subscription, I will need to assign it in connectionString variable, right?

Comment: Thank you sir Panagiotis Kanavos for your comment!